# When gRPC client throws RpcException on a method, how do you obtain the innerException for Internal errors

Tags: c#, grpc, polly

I would like add resiliency between .NET Core 3.1 gRPC client/server using Polly.net to handle a back-off retry policy.

I'm not happy with the gRPC's `RpcException`. I'm wonder if there is a better way to detect the forced closed remote connection. This happens when grpc starts after client or restart of gRpc service.

The inner exception is `null` and only way to find the exception was to parse the error message -- not as reliable as I would like.

How can I get the Win32 exception within the `RpcException`?

```cs
private static IAsyncPolicy RetryTransientException()
{
    return Policy
        .Handle<RpcException>(rpcException => IsTransient(rpcException.StatusCode))
        .Or<RpcException>(IsRemoteForcedConnection)
        .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync(
            (retryAttempt, ctx) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
            (exception, retries, timeSpan, context) =>
            {
                context.GetLogger()?.Information(exception,
                    "[onRetry] {0} Transient error attempt {1} to reconnect with gRpc server.",
                    context.PolicyKey, retries);
            }
        )
        .WithPolicyKey(PolicyNames.PersistentClientStream + "-waitandretrytransienterrors");
}

private static bool IsTransient(StatusCode status)
{
    if (status == StatusCode.Unavailable)
        return true;
    if (status == StatusCode.DeadlineExceeded)
        return true;
    return false;
}

private static bool IsRemoteForcedConnection(RpcException rpcException)
{
    return rpcException.StatusCode == StatusCode.Internal
           && rpcException.Message.Contains("System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061)");
}
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Good idea to check the last win32 error. Should be ok assuming all gRPC status code of "Internal" are Win32 errors. If some are not Win32 errors risk obtaining an unrelated error. Really hoping there was something in the gRPC api for this.

Comment: I'm curious what you ended up doing. I'm stuck on net48 for the next 6 months.